# how to reload parent window on closing child window

Tags: javascript

```
function print() {
var popup;

            popup = window.open(URL2, "Popup", ",scrollbars=yes,statusbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes");//URL2 contains the path and pdf name
            popup.focus();
            popup.print();
            window.opener.location.reload();
}
```

in the above JAVASCRIPT function i am opening a popup window to show PDF and working fine till here but i also want a dialogue box to be prompted immediately after the popup window opens that is not working and i want to reload the parent window that is also not working using above function.

1- my problems  is when i am closing the popup i just want my parent window to reload but in the existing answers i did not find the solutions that would work
2- I want print dialogue functionality

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your function `print` is overriding the default `window.print` function, so you should choose a better name for yours. Second, you must wait for the popup to load, before open the dialog.

Your code updated:

```
function printing() {
  var popup = window.open(URL2, "Popup", ",scrollbars=yes,statusbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes");

  popup.onload = function() {
    popup.focus();
    popup.print();
    location.reload();
  }
}
```

Comment: print is still not working , and my parent page still not reloading

Comment: Fiddle working like a charm: http://jsfiddle.net/7fp5hh2j/4/

Comment: could it be browser problem as this is not working for me and my browser is IE7

Comment: and in fiddle also its not relaoding the parent

Comment: @ Buzinas  : this will not reload parent page even in any browser but my main concern is this. please help

Comment: bcz i am in one jsp page again using javascript on that window opening one window then how it willl reload parent using ur functionality the location.reload onunload event is happening at the time of pagent page onunload